# Pop!_OS: Spotify Downloader (spotdl: command not found)

Tags: software-installation, python, ffmpeg, python3

I recently installed `spotdl` (Spotify Downloader) by following the instructions given at [GitHub's Installation page](https://github.com/ritiek/spotify-downloader/wiki/Installation). However, when I try to run the tool and execute the commands provided at the [project page](https://github.com/ritiek/spotify-downloader), `Terminal` results with the following message: `spotdl: command not found`.

I am rather an inexperienced user with Linux, but I think I might have made an error in the installation process. See, the command that I ran to install the tool was `pip install -U spotdl` (according to the source number one). However, the source number two — that is the project page — tells to run a different command, `pip3 install spotdl`, emphasizing that the tool only works with `Python 3`. Well, before noticing the latter, I already had followed the steps provided by the former.

And that's not all. While running `pip install -U spotdl`, I received the following message:

> XXXXs@pop-os:~$ pip install -U spotdl
>
> Command 'pip' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install python-pip

Well, I decided to follow the advice and run the command above, resulting:

```
XXXXs@pop-os:~$ sudo apt install python-pip
[sudo] password for XXXXs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libvala-0.40-0 valac-0.40-vapi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-all python-all-dev
  python-dev python-pip-whl python-setuptools python-wheel python-xdg
  python2.7-dev
Suggested packages:
  python-setuptools-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-all python-all-dev
  python-dev python-pip python-pip-whl python-setuptools python-wheel
  python-xdg python2.7-dev
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 30.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 46.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04 [28.3 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpython-dev amd64 2.7.15~rc1-1 [7,684 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpython-all-dev amd64 2.7.15~rc1-1 [1,092 B]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-all amd64 2.7.15~rc1-1 [1,076 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04 [278 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-dev amd64 2.7.15~rc1-1 [1,256 B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-all-dev amd64 2.7.15~rc1-1 [1,100 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 python-pip-whl all 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1 [1,653 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 python-pip all 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1 [151 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 python-setuptools all 39.0.1-2 [329 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python-wheel all 0.30.0-0.2 [36.4 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 python-xdg all 0.25-4ubuntu1 [31.3 kB]
Fetched 30.8 MB in 50s (614 kB/s)                                              
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 257811 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libpython2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libpython-dev_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-all-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libpython-all-dev_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-all.
Preparing to unpack .../03-python-all_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-all (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../04-python2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-dev (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../05-python-dev_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-all-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../06-python-all-dev_2.7.15~rc1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-all-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip-whl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-python-pip-whl_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip-whl (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-pip.
Preparing to unpack .../08-python-pip_9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-pip (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-setuptools.
Preparing to unpack .../09-python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-setuptools (39.0.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-wheel.
Preparing to unpack .../10-python-wheel_0.30.0-0.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-wheel (0.30.0-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-xdg.
Preparing to unpack .../11-python-xdg_0.25-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-xdg (0.25-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-pip-whl (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Setting up python-setuptools (39.0.1-2) ...
Setting up python-wheel (0.30.0-0.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Setting up python-pip (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04) ...
Setting up python-all (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up python-xdg (0.25-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpython-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up python-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up libpython-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
Setting up python-all-dev (2.7.15~rc1-1) ...
XXXXs@pop-os:~$ pip install -U spotdl
```

Now, when I run `pip -V` in `Terminal`, I'll get the following:

```
XXXXs@pop-os:~$ pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
XXXXs@pop-os:~$
```

So this means I have indeed `Python 2` installed on my system, doesn't it? What should I do in this case? Remove `Python 2` from the system — to avoid bloating the system, if for nothing else — and install `Python 3`? But I don't know how to :-( Your kind help would be deeply appreciated!

Otherwise, I already have the newest version of `ffmpeg`:

```
@pop-os:~$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ffmpeg is already the newest version (7:3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libvala-0.40-0 valac-0.40-vapi
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
XXXXs@pop-os:~$
```

Oh, and this is the installation log of `spotdl`, just in case:

```
XXXXs@pop-os:~$ pip install -U spotdl
Collecting spotdl
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/6d/    b66a58f08890965f4afb94bc3738624407328fc12c081697ac18537d0446/spotdl-0.9.3.tar.gz
Collecting PyYAML    =3.12 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/    a3/65/837fefac7475963d1eccf4aa684c23b95aa6c1d033a2c5965ccb11e22623/PyYAML-5.1.1.tar.gz (274kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 276kB 944kB/s 
Collecting beautifulsoup4    =4.6.0 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/0e/    048a2f88bc4be5e3697df9dc1f7b9d5c9c75be62676feeeb91d2e896c5ea/beautifulsoup4-4.7.1-py2-none-any.whl (94kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 507kB/s 
Collecting logzero    =1.3.1 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/    97/24/27295d318ea8976b12cf9cc51d82e7c7129220f6a3cc9e3443df3be8afdb/logzero-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lyricwikia    =0.1.8 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/82/dfce4509b6097cdacfab4510a401ef007e8314a2d1d179267efd873d1a55/lyricwikia-0.1.9.tar.gz
Collecting mutagen    =1.37 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4c/    5ad1a6e1ccbcfaf6462db727989c302d9d721beedd9b09c11e6f0c7065b0/mutagen-1.42.0.tar.gz (925kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 931kB 717kB/s 
Collecting pafy    =0.5.3.1 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/e8/3516f761558525b00d3eaf73744eed5c267db20650b7b660674547e3e506/pafy-0.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathlib    =1.0.1 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/aa/9b065a76b9af472437a0059f77e8f962fe350438b927cb80184c32f075eb/pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 948kB/s 
Collecting spotipy    =2.4.4 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/46/3c957255c96910a8a0e2d9c25db1de51a8676ebba01d7966bedc6e748822/spotipy-2.4.4.tar.gz
Collecting titlecase    =0.10.0 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/78/5b9faa7b9288c9fa5a4fdb6989f5e675744511ab6cff0489a0c7744a4f6b/titlecase-0.12.0.tar.gz
Collecting unicode-slugify    =0.1.3 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/ba/1a05f61c7fd72df85ae4dc1c7967a3e5a4b6c61f016e794bc7f09b2597c0/unicode-slugify-0.1.3.tar.gz
Collecting youtube_dl    =2017.5.1 (from spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/05/908331f41e7ed52a3510c8927177056ffc7d26c3692ab87e3fad78081a05/youtube_dl-2019.6.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 613kB/s 
Collecting soupsieve    =1.2 (from beautifulsoup4    =4.6.0-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/a5/7ea40d0f8676bde6e464a6435a48bc5db09b1a8f4f06d41dd997b8f3c616/soupsieve-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting six (from lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting unidecode (from unicode-slugify    =0.1.3-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/42/d9edfed04228bacea2d824904cae367ee9efd05e6cce7ceaaedd0b0ad964/Unidecode-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (238kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 1.2MB/s 
Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache; python_version < "3" (from soupsieve    =1.2-    beautifulsoup4    =4.6.0-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/8e/2424c0e65c4a066e28f539364deee49b6451f8fcd4f718fefa50cc3dcf48/backports.functools_lru_cache-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,    =1.21.1 (from requests-    lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/60/247f23a7121ae632d62811ba7f273d0e58972d75e58a94d329d51550a47d/urllib3-1.25.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (150kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 1.4MB/s 
Collecting certifi    =2017.4.17 (from requests-    lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/1b/b853c7a9d4f6a6d00749e94eb6f3a041e342a885b87340b79c1ef73e3a78/certifi-2019.6.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (157kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 771kB/s 
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,    =3.0.2 (from requests-    lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 1.0MB/s 
Collecting idna<2.9,    =2.5 (from requests-    lyricwikia    =0.1.8-    spotdl)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 2.1MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: spotdl, PyYAML, lyricwikia, mutagen, pathlib, spotipy, titlecase, unicode-slugify
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spotdl ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/27/9b/65/5cd2c56c23f5566ace8fc31393943251124de819bd069f2d2c
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyYAML ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/16/27/a1/775c62ddea7bfa62324fd1f65847ed31c55dadb6051481ba3f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lyricwikia ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/5e/7d/5d/b77975b5cabfc8848a795a851b07b3fde7fd685b27e501d055
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mutagen ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/33/4c/c3/6189a75038a7b00a8bc77fcb4dbdc38de335c55443f6680b13
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pathlib ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/f9/b2/4a/68efdfe5093638a9918bd1bb734af625526e849487200aa171
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spotipy ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/76/28/19/a86ca9bb0e32dbd4a4f580870250f5aeef852870578e0427e6
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for titlecase ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/9f/fb/8f/4d61939e2447b1b8c13f6ceeca035383c14d4228e88b174402
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for unicode-slugify ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/XXXXs/.cache/pip/wheels/00/86/80/77ea75d401d5d6550a79179f76c6b26fe1280d40fb447ea4f3
Successfully built spotdl PyYAML lyricwikia mutagen pathlib spotipy titlecase unicode-slugify
Installing collected packages: PyYAML, backports.functools-lru-cache, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, logzero, urllib3, certifi, chardet, idna, requests, six, lyricwikia, mutagen, pafy, pathlib, spotipy, titlecase, unidecode, unicode-slugify, youtube-dl, spotdl
Successfully installed PyYAML-5.1.1 backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5 beautifulsoup4-4.7.1 certifi-2019.6.16 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.8 logzero-1.5.0 lyricwikia-0.1.9 mutagen-1.42.0 pafy-0.5.4 pathlib-1.0.1 requests-2.22.0 six-1.12.0 soupsieve-1.9.1 spotdl-0.9.3 spotipy-2.4.4 titlecase-0.12.0 unicode-slugify-0.1.3 unidecode-1.1.1 urllib3-1.25.3 youtube-dl-2019.6.21
XXXXs@pop-os:~$
```

I hope I haven't messed up anything entirely. Thanks a lot for your help in advance, and happy Midsummer's Day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 and Python 3 can be installed on the same system without conflict. You can install the Python 3 version of `pip` similar to how you installed the Python 2 version:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now, you you should be able to use `pip3` to install `spotdl`:

```
pip3 install spotdl
```

I just tried this on my own system and the installation failed when running the command as a regular user<sup>*</sup>; I had to install it as a superuser (using `sudo`) which successfully installed the program to `/usr/local/bin/spotdl`.

---

#### Removing Python 2 pip and packages installed by it

If you’re really constrained by resources, [What is the easiest way to remove all packages installed by pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11248073/1640661) shows how to remove the packages installed by `pip2`.

```
pip2 freeze | xargs pip2 uninstall -y
```

To remove the `pip2` Debian package, run `sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove dependencies that are no longer required.

---

<sup>*</sup> This could be due to too much messing around with installing `pip` and `pip3` from different sources years ago when I first installed my current system (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Thanks! How about the `pip install -U spotdl`? Is it now a separate installation of the `spotdl` tool for `Python 2`? It's just that I am a little bit minimalistic, and I'd rather remove all the unnecessary installations from my systems if I don't need them :-) So if it isn't too much trouble, could you please help me to uninstall `Python 2` and the related tool installation, `pip install -U spotdl` as well? It's the Midsummer's night here right now, and the clock is nearly 1 am, so I'll be back tomorrow. Anyway, thousand thanks for your kind help, Anthony Geoghegan! :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to remove the Python 2 packages installed by Python 2 pip and to then remove the package itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for my late reply, I really got knee deep in the hoopla while trying to solve other issues, which finally lead to a fresh install of Pop!_OS 19.04 on my system :-D

I'll soon install `pip3` on my system (no need to remove `pip2`, thank God), and then try to run `pip3 install spotdl` to see if it works. But I'll let you know and answer more precisely soon! Thanks still for your help kind and insightful.

Comment: Yepp! Worked great! Thanks for your kind help @AnthonyGeoghegan !

Comment: @Jayaguru-Shishya Glad to hear it helped. I don’t have too much time these days to answer questions but yours was well written with a good description of the problem – which is always good to see for someone’s first question (hence the upvote).